# Displaying Lakhs and Crores in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to use Google Sheets for its convenient global access, but I really need to display numbers in Lakh and Crore (Indian style) format to avoid confusion among managers.

`150,000` should display as `1,50,000` and `12,000,000` should display as `1,20,00,000`.

I tried setting the format to `##,##,##,000` but my number still displays as `12,000,000`. I couldn't find anything [in the docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?hl=en).

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Comment: This question isn't about programming related to Google Apps, so it is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It belongs on [WebApps](//webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Indian currency format displays numbers like below**

```
1 - One Rupee
10 - Ten Rupee
100 - One Hundred Rupee
1,000 - One Thousand Rupee
10,000 - Ten Thousand Rupee
1,00,000 - One Lac Rupee
10,00,000 - Ten Lac Rupee
1,00,00,000 - One Crore Rupee
```

So below formats seems to be correct.

**To show positive and negative INR/Rs. up to Lakh**

```
[>99999][$₹]##\,##\,##0.00;[<-99999][$₹]##\,##\,##0.00;[$₹]##\,##0.00
```

**To add support for positive lakhs and crores**

```
[>9999999][$₹]##\,##\,##\,##0.00;[>99999][$₹]##\,##\,##0.00;[$₹]##,##0.00
```

**Add support for negative lakhs and crores**

```
[<-9999999][$₹]##\,##\,##\,##0.00;[<-99999][$₹]##\,##\,##0.00;[$₹]##,##0.00
```

For Microsoft excel, add the above format at
Format -> Cells -> Custom -> [Custom text box]
[image]
Below screenshot demonstrates above custom format in use:

**Reference: https://www.raghunayak.com/2020/07/how-to-show-inrrs-in-lakh-crore-format.html**

Comment: That's great! One can simply add further instances of `,##\` to each side if they need to support larger numbers.

Comment: Easiest answer of all IMO. Thanks.

Answer (score 511):

This works in Google Sheets for sure. Should work in Excel too.

With the appropriate cells selected, navigate to:

```
Google Sheets : Format -> Number -> More Formats -> Custom Number Format
Excel : Format -> Cells -> Custom -> [Custom text box]
```

Enter one of the following and Apply:

A] For Lakhs and Crores with the Rupee symbol and decimals

```
[$₹][>9999999]##\,##\,##\,##0.00;[$₹][>99999]##\,##\,##0.00;[$₹]##,##0.00
```

B] For Lakhs and Crores with the Rupee symbol and without decimals

```
[$₹][>9999999]##\,##\,##\,##0;[$₹][>99999]##\,##\,##0;[$₹]##,##0
```

C] For Lakhs and Crores without the Rupee symbol and with decimals

```
[>9999999]##\,##\,##\,##0.00;[>99999]##\,##\,##0.00;##,##0.00
```

D] For Lakhs and Crores without both the Rupee symbol and decimals

```
[>9999999]##\,##\,##\,##0;[>99999]##\,##\,##0;##,##0
```

Edit: I've tested these on both Google Sheets and Excel. Negative numbers work as well.

Comment: This should be modified to work with negative values as well.

Comment: Google in all its glory totally forgot about 17% of world's population...

Comment: This formula is not working for negative numbers like -1,00,000. Can anyone expand this answer further for negative numbers

Comment: Not Working for More than 100 Cr as well as negative numbers, can somebody please modify this

Comment: for negative numbers, separately formatting formulas are mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36804356/how-to-format-numbers-as-lakhs-and-crores-in-excel-google-spreadsheet-when-the?rq=1 .. if we want both positive & negative, there is a limit of regex patterns u can include ( upto 4 ).. so google treats it as invalid format.. solution is: if you are aware of which columns are negative.. apply negative formatting to them.. for other columns.. apply positive formatting..

Comment: Thank you very much. The same problem exists when you search `1,00,000 + 1,00,000` on Google, it'll not show `2,00,000`, but if you search `100,000 + 100,000` it'll show 200,000. They don't seem to care about Indian it seems.

Comment: In Google sheets, if I use this, I cannot perform mathematical operations, I get an error saying `Function MINUS parameter 1 expects number values. But '54,00,000' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.`

Comment: We do not need these formats anymore, Google now has inbuild different currency formats.
Google Sheets : Format -> Number -> More Formats -> More Currencies

Comment: @shortduck The Google Indian rupee format, will only apply the symbol. It will still format the numbers in millions, billions instead of lakhs & crores.

Comment: Plus one. Also, make sure, you select custom number format, not custom currency format.

Comment: Need to display with RED (negative) and GREEN (positive) colors. How do I modify them?

Comment: @Anish Kuriakose - gr8 job. My sheet looks gr8 now.

Comment: It seems like a deliberate attempt by all major companies like microsoft, apple, google to push everyone to miles, millions and other unscientific American standards.

Comment: For A}  If the number is negative it does not format it correctly. Positive number works fine

Comment: It's not correct, it still display 1 lac as 100,000 but in Indian currency format, it supposed to be 1,00,000

Answer (score 6):

### new formula approach:

- works with numeric numbers
- works with plain text numbers
- works with text
- works with empty cells
- works with negative values
- works with zeros
- works with scientific notations
- works with decimals
- works up to Shankh
- works up to 10^±50

---

### indian separator system:

```
=INDEX(IF(IFERROR(N(ABS(A1:A*1)))>0, REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(
 REPT(0, 50)&"×"&TEXT(A1:A, "0"), REPT("(..)", 24)&"(...)$", 
 JOIN(",", "$"&SEQUENCE(25))), "(.*×,?)", ), "-,", "-")&
 IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A&"", "(\.\d{1})")), A1:A&""))
```

[image]

---

### indian short currency:

```
=INDEX(IF((IFERROR(N(ABS(A1:A*1)))>0)+(IF(ISBLANK(A1:A),,IFERROR(A1:A*1, 1)=0)), 
 REGEXREPLACE(TEXT(TRUNC(IFNA(A1:A*(10^-(
 VLOOKUP(LEN(TEXT(INT(ABS(A1:A*1)), "0")), 
 SEQUENCE(8, 1, 6, 2), 1)-1)), A1:A), 1), "0.#"), "(\.)$", )&" "&
 HLOOKUP(LEN(TEXT(INT(ABS(A1:A*1)), "0")), {0, SEQUENCE(1, 8, 4, 2); 
 SPLIT("Rp♦Rp♦L♦Cr♦Arab♦Kharab♦Nil♦Padma♦Shankh", "♦")} , 2), ""&A1:A))
```

[image]

---

### both indian systems combined:

```
=INDEX(IF((IFERROR(N(ABS(A1:A*1)))>0)+(IF(ISBLANK(A1:A),,IFERROR(A1:A*1, 1)=0)), 
 REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(
 REPT(0, 50)&"×"&REGEXREPLACE(TEXT(TRUNC(IFNA(A1:A*(10^-(
 VLOOKUP(LEN(TEXT(INT(ABS(A1:A*1)), "0")), 
 SEQUENCE(8, 1, 6, 2), 1)-1)), A1:A), 1), "0"), "(\.)$", ), REPT("(..)", 24)&"(...)$", 
 JOIN(",", "$"&SEQUENCE(25))), "(.*×,?)", ), "-,", "-")&
 IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A&"", "(\.\d{1})"))&" "&
 HLOOKUP(LEN(TEXT(INT(ABS(A1:A*1)), "0")), {0, SEQUENCE(1, 8, 4, 2); 
 SPLIT("Rp♦Rp♦L♦Cr♦Arab♦Kharab♦Nil♦Padma♦Shankh", "♦")} , 2), A1:A&""))
```

[image]

---

---

### [english demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R6EpDjX3_BnySrGl2AIUPYw37LIAEEYbkyp8fCQ_soI/copy)

### [non-english demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vYxwjU_flCZoh7IWDKLfHflEynHc0yhvoY-4Qjsp0S4/copy)

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately, internal formatting is able to work only with 3 types (**[see more here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69773823/5632629)**) if you need to get more from indian currency system you can use a formula like below either for separator system or short currency system respectively

[image]

---

### indian separator system in B2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(IFERROR(
 REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, REPT("(.)", IF(LEN(A2:A)=3, LEN(A2:A)-4, LEN(A2:A)-3))), "0"), 
 "select "&JOIN(",", "Col"&SORT(SEQUENCE(MAX(LEN(A2:A)-3)), 1, )))),,9^9)), " ", ), 
 "(.{2})", "$1,"), REPT("(.)", IF((LEN(A2:A)-3)+ROUNDDOWN((LEN(A2:A)-3)/2)<1, 1, 
 (LEN(A2:A)-3)+ROUNDDOWN((LEN(A2:A)-3)/2)))),
 "select "&JOIN(",", "Col"&SORT(SEQUENCE(MAX((LEN(A2:A)-3)+
 ROUNDDOWN((LEN(A2:A)-3)/2))), 1, )))),,9^9)), " ", ), "^,", )&","&IFNA(
 REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "...$"), IF(A2:A="",,TEXT(A2:A, "000"))), "^0,$", ))
```

---

### indian short currency in C2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(ROUND(A2:A*VLOOKUP(LEN(A2:A), {SEQUENCE(19), 
 {1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 10^-5; 10^-5; 10^-7; 10^-7; 10^-9; 10^-9; 
  10^-11; 10^-11; 10^-13; 10^-13; 10^-15; 10^-15; 10^-17; 10^-17}}, 2, 1), 2)&" "&
 VLOOKUP(LEN(A2:A), {SEQUENCE(19), 
 {"Rp"; "Rp"; "Rp"; "Rp"; "Rp"; "L"; "L"; "Cr"; "Cr"; "Arab"; "Arab"; 
  "Kharab"; "Kharab"; "Nil"; "Nil"; "Padma"; "Padma"; "Shankh"; "Shankh"}}, 2, 1)))
```

- side note: `ROUND` is set to 2 decimal places. this can be set to 0, or `ROUND` can be completely removed, or it can be replaced by `TRUNC` if needed

---

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jpXvZSDD2kBj1OnGQUIIBVzKcDUB240IGGQpm1bZDv0/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 0):

### July 2023: Another option is to use formula on cell value:

```
=CONCATENATE("₹", 
 if(abs(B3)<100000,B3,
  if(abs(B3) <10000000,text(B3/100000,"#.0")&" Lakh",
   if(abs(B3)<=1000000000,text(B3/10000000,"#.0")& "Crore", 
      text(B3/10000000,"#.0")& "Crore"))
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can modify formula to extend it to *arab*, *kharab* etc.

Comment: Here the problem is for example if the value is 72,06,000 (72 Lakhs and 6 Thousands) then it converts it into 72.1Lakhs rather than 72.06 Lakhs.