# How to format numbers as lakhs and crores in excel/ google spreadsheet when the number could be negative too?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have to format numbers in the Indian formatting system with commas showing up for lakhs(1,00,000) and crores (1,00,00,000).

This answer works for positive numbers

[Displaying Lakhs and Crores in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32359814/displaying-lakhs-and-crores-in-google-sheets/36804297#36804297)

But negative numbers show the commas for millions and billions only. How do I make one format work for both positive and negative?

Comment: This question isn't about programming related to Google Apps, so it is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It belongs on [WebApps](//webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe excel formatting can take a max of 2 conditions, plus a default if those conditions aren't met.

To get around this I think your only option is conditional formatting.

Using one example from your linked solution I would put this in cell formatting.

```
[$₹][>9999999]##\,##\,##\,##0.00;[$₹][>99999]##\,##\,##0.00;[$₹]##,##0.00
```

Then in conditional formatting you would need to have a condition `if cell<0` and apply the conditional format of:

```
[<-9999999][$₹]-##\,##\,##\,##0.00;[<-99999][$₹]-##\,##\,##0.00;[$₹]##,##0.00
```

If you want to change decimals, symbols, etc you should be able to work it out from the linked solution and this one