# Google Sheets custom number format - Lakh and Crore suffix

Tags: google-sheets, number-formatting

In google sheets, I need a way to display currency as follows:

- Cell data: 2000000, Display: 20L
- Cell data: 30000000, Display: 3Cr

Tried the "comma" formatter as explained [here](https://medium.com/@brookinc/the-only-spreadsheet-custom-number-format-you-ll-ever-need-7cc356a7ca3e) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32359814/displaying-lakhs-and-crores-in-google-sheets), but that does not work for my case.
How can we get [lakh/crore format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system)?

I found [this](https://chandoo.org/wp/custom-number-formats-multiply-divide-by-any-power-of-10/) which works for excel, anything similar for google sheets?

Comment: this may need to be done with formula coz internal formatting is too weak for this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying Lakhs and Crores in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32359814/displaying-lakhs-and-crores-in-google-sheets)

Comment: @Kessy the answer you suggested, simply places the comma at the correct place according to the Indian currency system, I don't want that

Comment: Can you share then what is your need? Also, have you tried creating the custom format?

Comment: @Kessy i want to type 2000000 in A1 and 3 0000000 in A2, then I should be able to sum them in A3 with value as 32000000, however the display should be A1 -> 20L, A2 -> 3Cr and A3 -> 3.2 Cr

I tried custom format but it only supports million, billion

Answer (score 0):

[image]

---

### indian separator system in B2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(IFERROR(
 REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, REPT("(.)", IF(LEN(A2:A)=3, LEN(A2:A)-4, LEN(A2:A)-3))), "0"), 
 "select "&JOIN(",", "Col"&SORT(SEQUENCE(MAX(LEN(A2:A)-3)), 1, )))),,9^9)), " ", ), 
 "(.{2})", "$1,"), REPT("(.)", IF((LEN(A2:A)-3)+ROUNDDOWN((LEN(A2:A)-3)/2)<1, 1, 
 (LEN(A2:A)-3)+ROUNDDOWN((LEN(A2:A)-3)/2)))),
 "select "&JOIN(",", "Col"&SORT(SEQUENCE(MAX((LEN(A2:A)-3)+
 ROUNDDOWN((LEN(A2:A)-3)/2))), 1, )))),,9^9)), " ", ), "^,", )&","&IFNA(
 REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "...$"), IF(A2:A="",,TEXT(A2:A, "000"))), "^0,$", ))
```

---

### indian short currency in C2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(ROUND(A2:A*VLOOKUP(LEN(A2:A), {SEQUENCE(19), 
 {1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 10^-5; 10^-5; 10^-7; 10^-7; 10^-9; 10^-9; 
  10^-11; 10^-11; 10^-13; 10^-13; 10^-15; 10^-15; 10^-17; 10^-17}}, 2, 1), 2)&" "&
 VLOOKUP(LEN(A2:A), {SEQUENCE(19), 
 {"Rp"; "Rp"; "Rp"; "Rp"; "Rp"; "L"; "L"; "Cr"; "Cr"; "Arab"; "Arab"; 
  "Kharab"; "Kharab"; "Nil"; "Nil"; "Padma"; "Padma"; "Shankh"; "Shankh"}}, 2, 1)))
```

- side note: `ROUND` is set to 2 decimal places. this can be set to 0, or `ROUND` can be completely removed, or it can be replaced by `TRUNC` if needed

---

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jpXvZSDD2kBj1OnGQUIIBVzKcDUB240IGGQpm1bZDv0/edit#gid=0)

Comment: You have given a converter, it no longer has the required cell data.
I only want the display to change, data should be intact - so that I can continue to use the cell data in other operations like sum()

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Feature Request on Google's Issue tracker so they can implement this feature on sheets.

To do so, you have to go to the [Sheets API component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191608) and then create a new [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191608&template=823917)

Answer (score 0):

here is an improoved alternative approach...

#### indian separator system:

```
=INDEX(IF(IFERROR(N(ABS(A1:A*1)))>0, REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(
 REPT(0, 50)&"×"&TEXT(A1:A, "0"), REPT("(..)", 24)&"(...)$", 
 JOIN(",", "$"&SEQUENCE(25))), "(.*×,?)", ), "-,", "-")&
 IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A&"", "(\.\d{1})")), A1:A&""))
```

[image]

---

#### indian short currency:

```
=INDEX(IF((IFERROR(N(ABS(A1:A*1)))>0)+(IF(ISBLANK(A1:A),,IFERROR(A1:A*1, 1)=0)), 
 REGEXREPLACE(TEXT(TRUNC(IFNA(A1:A*(10^-(
 VLOOKUP(LEN(TEXT(INT(ABS(A1:A*1)), "0")), 
 SEQUENCE(8, 1, 6, 2), 1)-1)), A1:A), 1), "0.#"), "(\.)$", )&" "&
 HLOOKUP(LEN(TEXT(INT(ABS(A1:A*1)), "0")), {0, SEQUENCE(1, 8, 4, 2); 
 SPLIT("Rp♦Rp♦L♦Cr♦Arab♦Kharab♦Nil♦Padma♦Shankh", "♦")} , 2), ""&A1:A))
```

[image]

---

#### both indian systems combined:

```
=INDEX(IF((IFERROR(N(ABS(A1:A*1)))>0)+(IF(ISBLANK(A1:A),,IFERROR(A1:A*1, 1)=0)), 
 REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(
 REPT(0, 50)&"×"&REGEXREPLACE(TEXT(TRUNC(IFNA(A1:A*(10^-(
 VLOOKUP(LEN(TEXT(INT(ABS(A1:A*1)), "0")), 
 SEQUENCE(8, 1, 6, 2), 1)-1)), A1:A), 1), "0"), "(\.)$", ), REPT("(..)", 24)&"(...)$", 
 JOIN(",", "$"&SEQUENCE(25))), "(.*×,?)", ), "-,", "-")&
 IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A&"", "(\.\d{1})"))&" "&
 HLOOKUP(LEN(TEXT(INT(ABS(A1:A*1)), "0")), {0, SEQUENCE(1, 8, 4, 2); 
 SPLIT("Rp♦Rp♦L♦Cr♦Arab♦Kharab♦Nil♦Padma♦Shankh", "♦")} , 2), A1:A&""))
```

[image]

---

- works with numeric numbers
- works with plain text numbers
- works with text
- works with empty cells
- works with negative values
- works with zeros
- works with scientific notations
- works with decimals
- works up to Shankh
- works up to 10^±50

---

### [english demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R6EpDjX3_BnySrGl2AIUPYw37LIAEEYbkyp8fCQ_soI/copy)

### [non-english demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vYxwjU_flCZoh7IWDKLfHflEynHc0yhvoY-4Qjsp0S4/copy)