# Convert 20,385.0 into 20 385,00 $ in a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, number-formatting, currency-formatting

In my Google Spreadsheet, I often have to paste numbers with that similar format 20,385.0. I tried to press the dollar sign to convert it into 20 385,00 $, but it didn't work. I tried to format it with Format -> Number -> Custom Number Format, but I never succeeded it. How can I convert this format 20,385.0 into this format 20 385,00 $?

Comment: Which cell format did you try?

Comment: You can do it with a custom number format. `Click Format | Number | Custom Number`, then use `#,##0.00[$$`

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/32359814/1595451

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular It does not seem to work. Are you sure this is fine?

Comment: Sorry - missed a trailing `]` in the comment. Try `#,##0.00[$$]`

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular If I take 19,556.0 with your solution, it seems to do nothing at all.