# How to get values using custom number format in single formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

How to get values using custom number format in single formula in Google Sheets?

I want values >10000000 Crore to be 1Cr, >100000 Lakh to be 1L, <99999 Thousand to be 99T

I have tried something like this

```
[<100000]0.00,"K";#\.00"L"

[<10000000]#\.00,"L";#\.0000,"Cr"
```

But this is two different formulas and I want a single formula

Comment: Is this Q&A helpful? [Displaying Lakhs and Crores in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32359814/1330560). There are also a couple of other questions about formatting of Indian Currency, have you researched these?